# Integration TestLink with Mantis

Tags: testlink, mantis

I'm trying to do integration between Testlink in this version - 1.9.10 and Mantis. I'm a bit lost. Has someone done it or has any idea how to carry out this? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you already unlost and did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the configuration example. For me this was OK with configuration `(Issue tracker management Type: mantis (Interface: soap))`, but I have a "standard Mantis installation", as shown in the example

```
<issuetracker>
<username>[my username, not a e-mail]</username>
<password>[my password]</password>
<uribase>http://mantis.slavaqa.pp.ua/</uribase>

<!-- Configure This if you want be able TO CREATE ISSUES -->
<project>Money House</project>
<category>[All Projects] Bug</category>
</issuetracker>
```